# Implementing CQRS with OOP in Java

Tags: java, oop, cqrs

I have an API where representation of query and entity model is represented by the same class. A simplified version :

```
class Model {
  private Long id;
  private Double a;
  private Double b;
  ...
}
```

The problem is that those properties together make no sense as query object. It does not need `id` altogether, and `a`, `b` are exclusive. Code is hard to understand without proper separation. My plan involves creating separate query classes: `A` and `B` for each type of key.

What makes me worry though is that in order to avoid using `instanceof` (any code assuming knowledge of all query types) I will need to implement all cross cutting concerns in query objects. For example, mapping to `WHERE` clause as part of actual `SQL` query.

To avoid client having implicit dependency on implementation my initial plan is to create server side classes that extend each POJO `A` and `B` and implement details there. This requires additional mapping layer to map from `A` to some other class that will implement a `sqlQuery()` operation (simplifying matters).

Question: Since this seems is complex enough, is there some standard approach for this kind of problem? References, patterns welcome.

Comment: Cannot quite get the question can you provide a more concrete example ? are a and b actually doubles in your domain ?

Answer (score 0):

As you sayed implementing separate query classes seems to be a good idea. The GOF's strategy pattern could be a good point to start at, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern